# Ghostscript / pdfwrite produces grey page in colored PDF and CMYK color instead of RGB

Tags: php, colors, ghostscript

### Background

In a PHP web application, I use DomPDF to create a dynamic PDF from HTML and CSS and Ghostscript's `pdfwrite` device to merge that dynamically created PDF with two existing third-party PDFs.

I have 3 environments with different ghostscript versions:

```
Dev  (Win10)    GPL Ghostscript 8.64 (2009-02-03) 
Test (Linux)    GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08) 
Prod (Linux)    GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)
```

### Problem

#### Expected

- All pages merged in the resulting PDF
- No *obvious* color differences

#### Actual Result

- All pages merged in the resulting PDF
- Colors look as expected in Dev and Test environments (Testing with Adobe Reader on Win10)
- In the Prod environment, the dynamic (DomPDF created) page

  - looks grey instead of colored
  - seems to have CMYK instead of RGB color, as identified by ImageMagick 6.9.9-34 Q16 x86:

The DOMPDF-created PDF itself, which is the input to `gs` here, looks just fine.

#### `identify` output on the PDFs

(ImageMagick 6.9.9-34 Q16 x86)

Output on **Dev**:

```
XXX.pdf[0] PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit sRGB 69761B 0.000u 0:00.010
XXX.pdf[1] PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit sRGB 69761B 0.000u 0:00.004
XXX.pdf[2] PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit sRGB 69761B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Output on **Prod**:

```
XXX.pdf[0] PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 2004080B 0.016u 0:00.013
XXX.pdf[1] PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 2004080B 0.016u 0:00.007
XXX.pdf[2] PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 2004080B 0.000u 0:00.003
```

All input PDFs to `gs` on Prod are sRGB, according to `identify`:

```
<third-party-pdf> PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit sRGB 65728B 0.000u 0:00.000
<dompdf-created>  PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit sRGB 29348B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Note:** I'm not sure what `identify`'s color space means exactly (as PDF documents or even pages pages do not need to have a single color space AFAIK). While most objects are RGB, the third-party PDFs may contain some Pantone-colored objects as well.

### What I've tried so far

- Initial command line was `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile={$concatenatedPDFTempFileName} {$pdfsToConcatString}` (PHP Variable syntax here)
- Spent a few hours trying to find documentation or other resources on this
- 3 way diff between `gs` options in all environments.
- tried combinations of different obvious command switches like `-sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -dUseCIEColor=true -sOutputICCProfile=default_rgb.icc`
- tried applying the exact options as in the test environment to the ghostscript on prod, but I did not manage to output them in an easily reusable format (maybe someone has a hint on that?)

Maybe someone knows what is the most promising approach to further investigation, or for example, how I can apply the exact gs configuration of the test environment to the prod environment (I doubt it is 100 % possible as there are different versions involved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Using three different (and all rather elderly, even the newest is 6 years old) versions of Ghostscript certainly isn't going to help.

First thing to note is that Ghostscript does **not** 'merge' PDF files. The actual process is described [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.26/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)

So all the input files will be completely interpreted, broken down into graphics primitives and then a new file re-assembled. Now in general, unless otherwise instructed, the pdfwrite device will attempt to maintain colour specifications in the original colour space. You are correct in your point that a PDF file may contain multiple different colour spaces, so I would treat the 'identify' results with a large degree of caution.

You haven't supplied the input file, nor any of the output files, so I can't perform any analysis of them, so its not really possible to tell you what's going on. Ghostscript itself, and the pdfwrite device does not have any 'configuration' in the way I think you are expecting. All the configuration is done through the command line, so if you are running the same command line for all the installations, then you are running the same 'configuration'.

I'm not sure why you are having trouble 'appying the exact options'. Surely you can determine the Ghostscript command line that your own code is creating ?

Anyway older versions are, obviously, less feature-rich and capable than newer versions. Its conceivable that there's a bug specific to your 8.70 version which is due to a new feature, that had a problem in that version (note the minor version number bump here indicates something significant changed). That could also explain why you get sRGB from your (very) old version and CMYK from your newer version.

If you supply the files to look at I'll tell you what the differences are. My advice would be to use the same version on all three platforms though, and I'd suggest that using software which is less than 6 years old would probably help. Not least because you are leaving yourself open to a number of known, published security exploits. At least one of which has been seen 'in the wild'.

I also would **not** use some of the command line switches you have supplied, -dUseCIEColor is a terrible idea, don't do that (newer versions of Ghostscript will specifically warn you if you do). Don't change the ColorConversionStrategy without a good reason. The colour management changed **totally* between the 8.x and 9.x series, prior to that -sOutptuICCProfile will have no effect whatsoever, so you are trying to apply controls that are not supported in the earlier version.

Comment: Sorry for my very late reply. You are completely right remarking that we should not be using 9 year old software. I advised my customer that we needed a better production environment. We agreed on a course of action that will hopefully soon make that happen. Thanks.